# :hover over <div> does not apply to all its child elements

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angularjsJS to create a list with the ng-repeat directive. This list contains 3 divs inside itself, which are layed out using floats. The idea is to change the background color of the entire div whenever the user moves the mouse inside the div's area. Below is the code I am using:

HTML

```
        <div class="concert-item" ng-repeat="(key, concert) in value">
          <div class="selfie item-float-left">
            <img alt src="[[[concert.author.selfie]]]" class="img-circle"/>
          </div>
          <div class="item-float-left">
            <p class="event-header">[[[concert.author.displayName]]]</p>
            <p>[[[concert.venue]]]</p>
            <p>[[[concert.dateInMs | timeFilterShort]]] @ [[[concert.beginTimeShort]]]</p>
          </div>    
          <div class="item-float-right">
            <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=[[[concert.street]]],[[[concert.zipCode]]]&output=classic" target="_blank">
              <img alt src="{{static '/img/MapIcon@50px.png'}}"/>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>              
        </div>
```

CSS (less)

```
.concert-item :hover{
    background-color: @light-gray-font-color;
}
```

With this code, when the user hovers over any of the div's children, only the background of that child element is modified. The rest of the div's area is not affected by the :hover setting.

I would appreciate is someone can provide any pointers about how to make the whole div's area change its background color when the mouse moves inside any point within the div's area.

Comment: .concert-item has a height of 0px because all its children are floating

Comment: apply the :hover to parent div (`.concert-item:hover`). Adding space to the `:hover` is mean hover for child elements, not the parent.

Comment: Thank you @sol !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the :hover to the actual parent div.  If you lose the space in your LESS so it looks like this:

```
.concert-item:hover{
    background-color: @light-gray-font-color;
}
```

It should work the way you want.

Comment: yep, that space before :hover was screwing things up. Thanks for the pointer, it works as expected now.